# Trying to write Automator app to open Automatic 1111

Tags: macos, url, terminal, automator

I recently started playing with Stable Diffusion, and specifically Automatic 1111. Since it's not exactly a standard macOS app because it needs to be open with a CLI command and then loaded in a browser, I thought I would just do an app in Automator, thinking it was very easy, but apparently not so much.

This is the sequence of actions I do every time I want to open A1111:

1. Click on the Terminal icon in the dock
2. Switch to Notes where I have the launch command, copy it and paste it into the Terminal. The command is: cd ~/stable-diffusion-webui;./webui.sh
3. When I hit enter, the Terminal shows me a bunch of stuff for about 20 seconds until it's done, and is ready for receiving instructions from the webUI.
4. I open Safari, click on the A1111 bookmark, which opens the URL http://127.0.0.1:7860/ and loads the web GUI for A1111. Super easy, but a bit of a pain after you do several times a day, and I think there has to be a better way of doing this.

So I opened Automator, set it to create an app, and started searching for commands I thought might work. And this is what I came up with, but it doesn't work:

[Automator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zp8w.jpg)

When I run the app, there's like a sprocket in the menu bar that spins, but when I click it, it says it's at 0%. And if I open Safari and load that URL/IP address, it does load the webUI. But my goal is to do this in a way that is just one click.

I tried the record function, but it looks like it's rather half-assed because it records everything, including mouse pointer motions that I don't need, but it doesn't record that text is being pasted, which wouldn't be ideal anyway because it would need to be text being input in the CLI and then the browser.

Incredibly, I can't find any command that would allow me to simply type a predetermined string. And also I can't see a way to simply open an URL. I mean, I put that "Get specified URLs" module there because it's the closest I could find.

What I need can't be that hard, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not what you are looking for, but I did it with shortcuts in the following way.

[image]

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd stable-diffusion-webui 
        ./webui.sh"
end tell
```

You can download the shortcut [here](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/c27dba09211d42cdb36b75504520a9b0).

Comment: Thank you! That works to an extent, but for some reason it opens Terminal with the default window size I set in the settings, but it opens an additional very small window for Stable Diffusion, with the default as it comes when you first install macOS, which is all white text and very small fonts.

Comment: Also, is there a way to pause the opening of Safari for about 25 seconds? That's about how long it takes for SD to open and be ready for input from the webUI.

Comment: Hi! Yes, you can add a waiting period and then add a action to open http://127.0.0.1:7860/ . I´m going to add this in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. So I take it that there's no way to open Terminal in the default theme like when I do manually? I see there's a command do open the Terminal or any other app. But I would like to do that as a first step, then have it type that text inside the terminal, then have it press Enter, wait for the 25 seconds, then open the URL. That's not possible? I know the end result is the same, but if I do it manually, it opens Terminal in full screen with the Homebrew theme set to larger fonts as I have it. This way works, but it opens Terminal in a tiny screen with small text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

Open the webui.sh in a text editor and chane the line

```
#export COMMANDLINE_ARGS=""
```

and change it to

```
#export COMMANDLINE_ARGS="--autolaunch"
```

Then you may want to play with platypus to make your own launcher.